# Multiply each column of a matrix by another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have a `M x N` matrix. I want to multiply each of the `N` columns by a `M x M` matrix. The following does this in a loop, but I have no idea how to vectorize it.

```
 u=repmat(sin(2*pi*f*t),[n 1]);
 W = rand(n);
 answer = size(u);
 for i=1:size(u,2)
   answer(:,i) = W*u(:,i);
 end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply need to multiply the two matrices:

```
answer = W*u;
```

Think about it: in every iteration of your loop you multiply a matrix by a vector. The result of that operation is a vector, which you save into your answer in column i. Matrix multiplication is a similar thing: you can understand it as multiplication of a matrix (W) by a set of vectors, which form your matrix u.

So your code is good, just remove the loop :)

Comment: Not sure if just spaced out or actually retarded. :-) Thanks.