# Multiply multiple columns in a matrix by another column in same matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I've seen the answers about multiplying one matrix by another.  But I have a single matrix, completely numerical.
As an example:

```
matrix = read.table(text = 
"ID  Mult    t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
 4   0.164   10  20  30  40  50
 16  0.581   5   10  5   10  5
 42  0.008   16  17  18  19  20
 91  0.328   20  20  20  20  20
 103 0.108   103 42  56  84  61", 
 h = T)
```

I want to multiply `t1` through `t5` by the multiplier, separately,  and put the results in new columns in my matrix.

I would do it column by column, but for the fact that I have over 200 columns!

Hopefully, someone can suggest a more simple fix.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's always a good idea to list other sources you've consulted, and explaining how your situation is different (otherwise your question may get flagged as a repeat). Have you looked at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12673891/1152809)? Also, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1152809) on how to ask an R question that easily allows others to help you. It specifies using `dput` to output your data so that we can easily run it on our local R and see what you see. Also, don't forget to upvote anything helpful, and mark an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df=read.table(text="ID  Mult    t1  t2  t3  t4  t5
4   0.164   10  20  30  40  50
16  0.581   5   10  5   10  5
42  0.008   16  17  18  19  20
91  0.328   20  20  20  20  20
103 0.108   103 42  56  84  61",h=T)

df[,c(paste0(colnames(df[,grepl("^t.*",colnames(df),perl = T)]),"bis"))]=df[,grepl("^t.*",colnames(df),perl = T)]*df$Mult
```

`df[,grepl("^t.*",colnames(df),perl = T)]` subsets `df` to only have the columns starting with "t"
`df[,c(paste0(colnames(df[,grepl("^t.*",colnames(df),perl = T)]),"bis"))]` take the `colnames()` of the previous subset, and concatenate them using `paste0()` with "bis" or any string to indicate the change. This creates the new columns which are filled with the results of the multiplication.

```
> df
   ID  Mult  t1 t2 t3 t4 t5  t1bis t2bis t3bis t4bis t5bis
1   4 0.164  10 20 30 40 50  1.640 3.280 4.920 6.560 8.200
2  16 0.581   5 10  5 10  5  2.905 5.810 2.905 5.810 2.905
3  42 0.008  16 17 18 19 20  0.128 0.136 0.144 0.152 0.160
4  91 0.328  20 20 20 20 20  6.560 6.560 6.560 6.560 6.560
5 103 0.108 103 42 56 84 61 11.124 4.536 6.048 9.072 6.588
```

Answer (score 0):

Some don't like loops, but I do sometimes. This is one of those times :)

```
mydf<-matrix
for (i in 3:length(mydf)){
  mydf[,length(mydf)+1] <- mydf$Mult * mydf[i]
}
mydf
   ID  Mult  t1 t2 t3 t4 t5   t1.1  t2.1  t3.1  t4.1  t5.1
1   4 0.164  10 20 30 40 50  1.640 3.280 4.920 6.560 8.200
2  16 0.581   5 10  5 10  5  2.905 5.810 2.905 5.810 2.905
3  42 0.008  16 17 18 19 20  0.128 0.136 0.144 0.152 0.160
4  91 0.328  20 20 20 20 20  6.560 6.560 6.560 6.560 6.560
5 103 0.108 103 42 56 84 61 11.124 4.536 6.048 9.072 6.588
```